# How to Socket Communication between 2 different Amazon EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, tcp

I am trying to communicate from EC2 to another EC2 via socket.

Is there anything that I need to consider except configuring security group?

These to EC2s are completely separated.

(I mean they are running on different amazon account separately)

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('#IP ADDRESS', #PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)

client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
data = server_socket.recv(1024)
print(data)
```

In addition, is it the right code to use? (Server Side, not a Client)

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your security group in order to accept connections in your bound port. Of course, you need a TCP connection for this and you need to open the ports on both instances, not just one. For example, if you want to listen on the port 8080, you would need to add the following rule (the one in the end).

[image]

One thing with your code though, when your `server_socket` accepts a connection, it will generate a new socket where you will be receiving the messages. In your case, you called `client_socket`. This new socket is the one that will receive the message, not your server_socket. I changed the name to `connection_socket`.

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('#IP ADDRESS', #PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)

connection_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
data = connection_socket.recv(1024)
print(data)
```